# How to create multiple RDD rows from a single file record in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, split, rdd

I'm struggling with the following logic using Apache Spark. My input file has rows in the following format pipe-delimited:

```
14586|9297,0.000128664|9298,0.0683921
14587|4673,0.00730174
14588|9233,1.15112e-07|9234,4.80094e-05|9235,1.91492e-05|9236,0.00776722
```

The first column is a key. There maybe one or more columns after that. Each subsequent column has a secondary key and a value, like this: 4673,0.00730174
While reading this file I want to have the resulted RDD having only 3 columns flattening other columns after the first one but retaining the main key, like these:

```
14586|9297,0.000128664
14586|9298,0.0683921
14587|4673,0.00730174
14588|9233,1.15112e-07
14588|9234,4.80094e-05
14588|9235,1.91492e-05
14588|9236,0.00776722
```

How can I do that in Scala?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the thing you're looking for?

```scala
val sc: SparkContext = ...
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  "14586|9297,0.000128664|9298,0.0683921",
  "14587|4673,0.00730174",
  "14588|9233,1.15112e-07|9234,4.80094e-05|9235,1.91492e-05|9236,0.00776722"
)).flatMap { line =>
  val splits = line.split('|')
  val key = splits.head
  val pairs = splits.tail

  pairs.map { pair =>
    s"$key|$pair"
  }
}

rdd collect() foreach println
```

Output:

```
14586|9297,0.000128664
14586|9298,0.0683921
14587|4673,0.00730174
14588|9233,1.15112e-07
14588|9234,4.80094e-05
14588|9235,1.91492e-05
14588|9236,0.00776722
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using *flatMap*? It allows you to create multiple 0-n rows from a single row of input. Just parse the line and reconstruct the row with the different values for the primary row key.

Comment: Micker, thanks for the advise. I tried that but probably was making a mistake and not getting a desired result. Do you mind posting a sample Scala code for that.

Comment: The code that @Pawel posted looks just fine to me. Obviously you won't need the setup or tear down code.